# Authentication in liferay pages

Tags: authentication, liferay, liferay-6

We are having a portlet on a liferay page. We want to put up up a permission on every action method that is performed. For example on page A we have landed an XYZ portlet. Now we want that whenever there is any action performed form this portlet, we want to check that if the user is having a role to perform this action or not.

It wont be a good approach to put up the code in Action method of the portlet cause we are having approximately 20 such pages and portlets.

Can we have some sort of filter or so, so that each action request is checked if the user is having the access to the content or not.

Thank you...

Comment: What is the scope of your permissions?
If i understand your request, the scope is the user role, the page and the portlet? Is that true?

Comment: We had made a role for each page(as of now). For each page if user is not having access to the page he is not able to view the portlet. Now what we want is that user will be able to see the page and the portlet. But we want to restrict the user if he is performing any action on that page. For ex A person is not having role for page A  then we want to show him the page and also the portlet, but we don't want him make an action request from that page. Is that Possible??

Comment: I think it wiil be a little hard to do.
What are the involved portlets?
Can you develop some custom things or are you limited to the 'control panel' capacities?

Comment: Dear Guli, We are having custom portlets. Sure we can develop more. We are open to all of the option.

Comment: i have an idea but it is a little bit to explain, i try to provide you an answer quickly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your Idea. That would be very helpful.

Comment: i make you an answer soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea.

### Use a filter to intercept all request

You can add a filter to the Liferay Servlet to check every request.
For that you can use a `hook-plugin`.

Look at this :

- http://www.liferay.com/fr/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/other-hooks
- http://connect-sam.com/2012/06/creating-servlet-filter-hook-in-liferay-6-1-to-restrict-access-based-on-ip-location/

Issue with filter is that you can't access `ThemeDisplay` or use `PortalUtil.getUser(request)`.

So you must use work around like that :

```
private User _getUser(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request);

    if (user != null) {
        return user;
    }

    String userIdString = (String) session.getAttribute("j_username");
    String password = (String) session.getAttribute("j_password");

    if ((userIdString != null) && (password != null)) {
        long userId = GetterUtil.getLong(userIdString);

        user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId);
    }

    return user;
}
```

### Filtering the request

To filter the request you must get :

- page id (Layout id in Liferay)
- portlet id
- portlet lifecycle

One more time using a filter is a pain because you can get the `ThemeDisplay`. These params are easy to get (with real object instancee) with `ThemeDisplay`.

So you must get this as parameter in the request.

```
final String portletId = ParamUtil.get((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest, "p_p_id", "");
final String layoutId = ParamUtil.get((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest, "plid", "");
final String portletLifecycle = ParamUtil.get((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest, "p_p_lifecycle", "");
```

Lifecycle details :

`portletLifecycle` is a `int` and the meaning of value is :

- 0 : `RENDER`
- 1 : `ACTION` (the one that interests you)
- 2 : `RESOURCE`

I think that with this data you can be able to define if user can or cannot make the action.

You can get user roles from the user.
You can get the current page and portlet linked to the request.
And you can know if the request is an action request.

Good luck with Liferay.

Comment: Have you finally find a solution to your requirements?

Comment: Can you expand on "Issue with filter is that you can't access ThemeDisplay or use PortalUtil.getUser(request)." - What does this mean / what is this issue? Is this a reported bug? Is it wrong to use getUser here? I'm getting null for getUser in a Filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can add freely configurable permissions to Liferay, see the [Developer Guide for detailed information](https://www.liferay.com/en/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/security-and-permissions-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-06-en). My first guess on this would be that these affect "model resources", e.g. the data that your portlet is dealing with, rather than portlet-resources, e.g. permissions on the individual portlet itself. Think of portlet-permissions as permissions that are defined by Liferay, model-resources as permissions where you can come up with your own vocabulary on the actions, e.g. "UPDATE_ADDRESS" etc.

These permissions will typically be tied to roles, which are granted to users/usergroups/etc.

Based on this variability, it depends on the nature of your permissions if you can write a filter to generically check permissions, or if it depends on more than the individual action call.

If you determine that there is a generic solution, look up PortletFilters, they behave just like ServletFilters. These can easily provide a home for permission checks.

It's quite hard to cover this topic in such a short answer, I hope to have given enough resources for you to continue your quest.

Answer (score 0):

You can abuse some existing portlet permission like "Add to Page" and set it to roles that should call the action.
And by the rendering and action phases validate "has the user necessary permission".

Or you can create new permission and configure it by portlet-configuration. This way is cleaner, but difficulty.